# Iterating dictionary swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary, iteration, option-type

I have below code in my project.

```
 for (key, value) in photoDic {
        if  let url = URL.init(string: value as! String){
        let photo : PhotoRecord = PhotoRecord.init(name:key as! String, url:url)
        self.photoRecords.append(photo)
        }
    }
```

My question is how can I make key and value in for loop optional, or check if either of them are nil?
I am not able to check if they are nil, getting warning saying any cannot be nil because it is nonoptional.

I was thinking of using something like 
for(key:String?, value:String?){}

But it is not working.

Comment: how do you declare your `photoDic`?

Comment: lazy var photoDic: NSDictionary = NSDictionary.init(contentsOf:URL.init(string: "http://www.raywenderlich.com/downloads/ClassicPhotosDictionary.plist")! )!

Comment: `key` of dictionary can never be nil, and `for in` always iterates non nil `value`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in a dictionary can't be an optional. (The key must conform to the `Hashable` protocol, and optionals don't.) So you **CAN'T** make the keys in your dictionary optional

If you want the values of your dictionary to be `Optionals` then you need to declare them as `Optionals`.

So, for example, change

```
let photoDic: [String: String] = ["key1": "http://www.someDomain.com/image.jpg"]
```

to

```
let photoDic: [String: String?] = ["key1": "http://www.someDomain.com/image.jpg"]
```

(Note that the type of `photoDic` is changed to `[String: String?]`.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already **all keys** in a dictionary are **non-optional by definition**.

Further in `NSDictionary` **all values** are **non-optional by definition**, too.

Be happy about that because

- There is no need to check for `nil`.
- The code will never crash.

A Swift dictionary can theoretically contain optional values but practically you are discouraged from using it. For compatibility reasons to `NSDictionary` a `nil` value indicates *key is missing*.